# Sqlalchemy - Insert into table if not exist in a column (Mysql)

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a simple Table like this

```
class Employeecode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employeecode'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    unique_code = Column(String(5), unique=True)
    employe_name = Column(String(50))
    designation = Column(String(50))
```

How i can create a function which will insert value into `'employeecode'` table if `'unique_code'` column doesn't have that value.

```
insert_unique(unique_code,employe_name,designation)
```

Comment: unique_code = Column(String(5),  unique=True) ?

Comment: I'd implemented it on the database level, it's not going to be efficient otherwise. It's DB-specific, but if you're running MySQL, you can use INSERT IGNORE INTO ... e.g.

execute(Employeecode.__table__.insert().prefix_with("IGNORE"), items)

Answer (score 0):

First you can store all previous unicode_value in a list and then you can check and run your query..

```
def function(**kwargs):
session = Session()
unique_list =[]
employeecodes = db.session.query(Employeecode).all()
for employee in employeecodes:
    unique_list.append(employee.unique_code)
if kwargs['unique_code'] not in unique_list:
    employee = Employeecode()  
    employee.unique_code = kwargs['unique_code']
    employee.employe_name = kwargs['employe_name']
    employee.designation = kwargs['designation']
    session.commit()
    retval = row2dict(employee)
    session.close()
    return retval
else:
    pass
```